# How create increment column in visidata from a set value, not for 1?

Tags: linux, spreadsheet, data-validation, range, column

If I have I frame with 10 rows, and I create a new column with za and then use gi I get a range column from 1 to 10, but instead of that I want to get a range column from 15 to 25.

How can I get that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.